# SQL's IN clause equivalent in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I wanted to know if there is any equivalent command in Core Data / Swift of MySQL's IN clause:

`"SELECT details FROM tbl_details WHERE ticket IN (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
let list = [1, 2, 3]
let inPred = NSPredicate(format: "ticket IN %@", list)
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "details")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
request.predicate = inPred
```

After that, call `context.executeFetchRequest` the usual way to retrieve the results.